# MySQL updating table with values selected from same table in one go

Tags: mysql

I want to update quite a few values in a table. Said values already exist in another table.

I'm selecting said values using the following query:

```
SELECT c.last_purchase, 
       so.customer_id,
       so.modified_at
  FROM customer c 
 INNER JOIN sale_order so  ON c.customer_id = so.customer_id 
                          AND c.country = so.country 
 WHERE so.created_at > c.last_purchase
```

So far so good. But my sql skills aren't too great(hey, I'm being honest here).

**The correct values are `so.modified_at`. I want to update `c.last_purchase` to match `so.modified_at`.**

Originally I was thinking of using a `WHEN` `THEN` combination. Or perhaps some sort of stored procedure.

I could this by using a bash script or any other programming language that knows how to connect to a database. But I'd like, if possible, to do this strictly using MySQL. If not possible I'll have to settle for a bash script(I already wrote one).

Honestly, I have no idea where to start.

Any pointing in the right direction is more than appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, you need to update `last_purchase` field with `modified_at` field by joining `customer` table and `sale_order` table using the conditions you mentioned in your query.

Then try the following query

```
UPDATE customer   AS c
  JOIN sale_order AS s 
   SET c.last_purchase = s.modified_at
 WHERE c.customer_id = s.customer_id
   AND c.country = s.country
   AND s.created_at > c.last_purchase;
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. I can't believe it was so obvious and I missed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is more efficient to move conditions back to the `JOIN ON` clause instead of using them in the `WHERE`. Plain `JOIN` creates the cartesian product of two tables that can be huge. If the resulting table is big enough not to fit into the join buffer then on-disk temporary table will be created that significantly slowdown the proceeding.

Comment: @Kondybas - Could u rewite the above query as an asnwer or comment ? Looking to learn.